# RabbitMQ queue length limit with flow control

Tags: rabbitmq

If I declare a queue with `x-max-length`, all messages will be dropped or dead-lettered once the limit is reached.

I'm wondering if instead of dropped or dead-lettered, RabbitMQ could activate the Flow Control mechanism like the [Memory/Disk watermarks](http://www.rabbitmq.com/memory.html). The reason is because I want to preserve the message order (when submitting; FIFO behaviour) and would be much more convenient slowing down the producers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to realize queue length limit on application level. Say, increment/decrement Redis key and check it max value. It might be not so accurate as native RabbitMQ mechanism but it works pretty good on separate queue/exchange without affecting other ones on the same broker.

**P.S.** Alternatively, in some tasks RabbitMQ is not the best choice and old-school relational databases (MySQL, PostgreSQL or whatever you like) works the best, but RabbitMQ still can be used as an event bus.

Comment: Yes I'm aware I can throttle on application level (with [channel.flow()](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#channel.flow) for instance). Although I was looking if RabbitMQ already implemented such mechanism in the broker itself.

Comment: Note, that RabbitMQ has limited `channel.flow` support https://www.rabbitmq.com/specification.html#method-status-channel.flow. In fact server does not support blocking flow with `active=true`.

Comment: And `channel.flow` works on channel level, so looks like it is not an option for you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There are two open issues related to this topic on the [rabbitmq-server github repo](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server).  I recommended expressing your interest there:

[Block publishers when queue length limit is reached](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/499)

[Nack messages that cannot be deposited to all queues due to max length reached](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/995)